# Are there symbols to represent tautology contradiction and contingency

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Are there any symbols to represent tautology contradiction and contingency?

Suppose I have a function that receives a formula and returns if this formula is a tautology, a contraction or a contingency. What could I use as the image of this function?

Comment: $\top$ (\top) is typically used for tautology, and $\bot$ (\bot) for contradiction. I haven't seen a symbol for contingency ... but I suppose you could use $\neg (\top \lor \bot)$ as an expression that is a contingency

Comment: See [Truth value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value) and [Logical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_constant).

Comment: I am thinking of using a combination of \top and \bot to represent contingency